# Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms Handler

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I override the FOSUserBundle Form like that:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->remove('username')
        ;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        ));
    }
}
```

The purpose is to remove the username field from the register form.
It works but when I'm using the form I have this error:

`Please enter a username`

So I'm trying to override the FormHandler by following this doc: https://symfony.com/doc/1.3.x/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html#overriding-form-handlers

But I didn't really get how to do it in my case where I am removing a field?

Here is my yaml file

```
# service.yml    
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
            tags:
                - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }

        app.form.handler.registration:
            class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler
            arguments: ["@fos_user.registration.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager", "@fos_user.mailer", "@fos_user.util.token_generator"]
            scope: request
            public: false

    # config.yml
    fos_user:
        db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
        firewall_name: main
        user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:
            group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
            group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
        service:
            user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
        registration:
            form:
                type: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
                handler: app.form.handler.registration
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added this code to my Entity User to make it work:

```
public function setEmail($email)
    {
        parent::setEmail($email);
        $this->setUsername($email);
    }
```